# Why does gnome-open-terminal not work as expected on MacBook?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, gnome

I have fedora installed on MacBook Pro, and also installed gnome-open-terminal on it.

On fodora 23 and before, when I right-click in the file explorer window, I can choose a menu item named "Open terminal here", and opened a terminal window as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]#
```

This is the same as I direct launch gnome-terminal from command line.

However, on fedora 24 running on MacBook Pro, even I do the same operations exactly, I get a new terminal window as follows:

```
sh-4.3#
```

I tested on VMware with fedora 24, the result is as expected. This weird issue only exists on MacBook Pro.

What's the cause?

Comment: What is root's shell in /etc/passwd?

Comment: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Comment: What machine is that?

Comment: MacBook Pro Retina 13# with pure Fedora 24 (default to GNOME)

Comment: This is very strange because sh-4.3 is the Bourne Shell. What prompt do you get if you type `bash` in your strange shell?

Comment: If I type bash and press Enter, the prompt will become: [root@localhost ~]#

Comment: What about `bash -l`?

Comment: If I type `bash -l` and press Enter, the prompt will also become: `[root@localhost ~]#`

Comment: What is the shell in the settings of gnome-terminal?

Comment: I don't know how to check the settings of gnome-terminal. I installed dconf-editor & gconf-editor & gsettings, but found nothing useful.

Comment: Check [Custom commands and shells](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en) in gnome-terminal. Is it set to /bin/sh? Also, see the INVOCATION section of [`man bash`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html).